# Función en xquery para generar un HTML no funciona

Tags: xml, xpath

Este es el `xquery` que estoy usando para una práctica, pero no consigo desentrañar el porqué no funcionan las variables en el return, llevo un par de horas pero aún no saco nada en claro, tengo otra versión que me funciona pero no es tan buena como esta:

```
 module namespace html = 'http://basex.org/modules/web-page';
declare
%rest:path('/CDs')
%output:method("html")
%output:doctype-system("about:legacy-compat")
function html:CDs()
as element(html)

{ 
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Xquery</title>
  </head>
  <body>
{

for $CDs in doc("cds.xml")//CD,  
$Artistas in doc("artistas.xml")//Artista,
$Canciones in doc("canciones.xml")//Cancion

where $CDs/idCancion/text() = $Canciones/idCancion/text() and
      $Artistas/idArtista/text() = $Canciones/idArtista/text() and
      $Artistas/Nombre = "James" and $Artistas/Apellidos = "Hetfield"

return <li>{data($CDs/idCD)}, {data($CDs/Titulo)} Artista: {data($Artistas/nombre)}, {data($Artistas/apellidos)}, idCancion: {data($Canciones/idCancion)}, Canción: {data($Canciones/nombreCancion)}.</li>
}
</body>
</html>
};
```

Un saludo y muchas gracias!

Comment: Ya he logrado solucionar los errores que me daban las variables pero aún no consigo que funcione y me genere el html con el join entre xml :p

Comment: Edita tu pregunta si la conseguiste una respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por recordarmelo!